# Scheduled Reminders for 'on behalf of' Memberships

Tags: civimember, scheduled-reminders

As far as my testing shows, setting up Scheduled Reminder for an Organisational membership is not resulting in a Reminder also going to the 'permissioned employee'.
Can anyone confirm steps that do result in the Reminder going to both the Org and their 'contact person'.
As I understand it, it is really the latter - getting the Reminder to the 'contact person' - that matters if we want to send out checksums.

Comment: Do you mean that scheduled reminders for memberships of organisations are not send to the organisation but only to the contact person? And I assume this is the case in the latest Civi version (4.6.2).

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the Memberships must be INHERITED by the permissioned employee as well.

Comment: Just to clarify, you're saying you've had success sending reminders to a contact that inherits a membership by relationship, right? I'm having some trouble with that so just want to verify that it should be possible, which seems to be what you're saying!

Comment: Based on my re-reading the above, my conclusion was it worked if the Permissioned employee also had inherited the Membership and the reason we were having the original problem is that we were testing with a contact that was a permissioned relationship but did NOT have the inherited membership