# Membership Set Up - Renewal Reminders - Inherited Memberships

Tags: civimember, scheduled-reminders

I am looking for some references on how renewal reminders are set up and whom they are sent to.

What I understand is:

**Membership WITHOUT Inherited Membership Set Up**

If an organization membership (“Membership Types” under CiviMember) is set up without a “Relationship Type” the main email (or primary email) of that organization is used by the system to send renewal reminders to.

**Membership WITH Inherited Membership Set Up**

If an organization membership is set up with a relationship type, the membership is automatically granted to the related contact as well. The membership will show up as inherited membership in the related contacts profile. In this case, the auto renewal reminder will be send to the organization primary email and the related contacts primary email.

Is my understanding of this correct? Do we need to consider anything when selecting the “location types” (main, billing, home, work) for the email address? Or will the auto renewal reminders always be sent to the “primary” email?

Comment: Possibly related: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/2111/scheduled-reminders-for-on-behalf-of-memberships