# Can inherited members receive scheduled reminders?

Tags: civimember, scheduled-reminders

In the scenario that organizations that have memberships, and then people are associated with the organization by relationship (and inherit that membership), it would be good to be able to send a scheduled renewal notice to the people that currently have the relationship with the organization. (Let's call that relationship "Representative is / Representative of"). The organization itself may not have a valid email address, and even if they do, it is probably not the right one that renewal notices should go to. The people who are currently "Representative of" the organization may change over the years while the organizational membership remains constant.

I have been trying to set up such a flow (as follows):

- Organization has membership
- Individuals have a relationship with the organization that inherits the membership
- A smart group filters these people (e.g. an active relationship, let's say) and this group is used in the scheduled reminders to limit reminders only to the appropriate people.
- Cron jobs are being fired (and the "Send Scheduled Reminders" cron job in particular is being fired).

However, no reminders appear to be going out.

In researching, I found [this PR](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/12510) and am trying to decipher if this relates.

> **After**
>
> A scheduled reminder is only excluded if
>
> - The membership triggering the reminder is inherited, and
> - The contact lacks relationship-based permission to edit the membership owner contact

Does this mean our entire scenario is unsupported? (ie. inherited memberships cannot receive Scheduled Reminders)?

There is also some description related to whether or not the relationship is permissioned for editing. In our scenario we would not choose to set this permissioning, but if that would solve this issue we might change our mind. I did a quick test and was not successful yet in getting a reminder to go out even with permissioning.

Comment: Related, perhaps, but from prior to the PR mentioned above: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/2111/scheduled-reminders-for-on-behalf-of-memberships/2324?noredirect=1#comment35185_2324

Comment: i only skim read but i don't see that you are saying the also have 'current employee of' which i think was the point i was making in the other SE i.e. they need ALL of 'current employee' + "permissioned" + "inherited membership" - but i may have missed the nuance in your above Q

Comment: @petednz-fuzion Oh, I did not catch that at all. In this case they are not employees and do not have that relationship. Thanks for following up. I'll do some testing with that in mind and if that works I'll have to see if they are okay adding that relationship even though it's technically incorrect in this case. Thanks for following up.

Answer (score 1):

Confirm that they have ALL of following conditions met:

- current employee relationship that is also permissioned
- inherited membership